# Na falta de um SUPT, posso fazer perguntas que envolvam hardware no site?

Tags: debate

Fiz essa pergunta aqui no SOPT

[A desfragmentação do disco rígido pode auxiliar no desempenho do meu servidor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103418/a-desfragmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-disco-r%C3%ADgido-pode-auxiliar-no-desempenho-do-meu-servidor/103429#103429)

E ganhei alguns votos negativos provavelmente de usuários que consideram a  pergunta fora de escopo em relação ao site.

Eu tive que dar um tapa na pergunta, para ela ficar "parecendo sobre programação".

No início a pergunta era:

```
Como funciona um processo de desfragmentação
```

Se eu tivesse desejo de compartilhar alguns conhecimentos específicos nesse área ou então de tirar alguma dúvida, teria que ir para outra ferramenta (como o SUEn)?

A questão é : Posso perguntar isso aqui no site ou não? Pois seria uma perca de tempo elaborar uma pergunta que vai ser negativada e marcada como fora de escopo tão rápido como o cometa de pegasus (gostei desse jargão).

Pois isso estou postando aqui no meta ;) Valeu!

Comment: Bem-vindo à zona cinzenta.

Comment: #freesupt #jesuissupt